# encriptacion url mediante javascript

Tags: php, javascript, md5

tengo la siguiente ruta en una tabla

```
<a   href="javascript:mostrarnoticia(<?php echo $row ['noticias_id']; ?>)"> 


            <img style="" src="<?php echo 'includes/includes/includes/'.$row['foto'];?>">
        </a>
```

y la **funcion** del **js**

```
function mostrarnoticia (id){
    window.location.href='noticiacompleta.php?noticias='+id;
    return;
  }
```

con el id de la href noticias_id el abrira por medio de la funcion la hoja llamada noticiacompleta.php y la url me la mostrar con el id del registro  de la siguiente manera

```
http://localhost/musica/noticiacompleta.php?noticias=2
```

siendo ese 2 el id del registro y noticias= el nombre de la tabla en la db

como puedo eviar que me muestre dicho **id** en la **url** **encriptandola**

Answer (score 1):

Encriptar el ID de la notica no es práctico y tampoco es aconsejable.
Pero por otro lado si es una buena práctica que el ID con el que se ve la noticia, no sea fácil de intercambiar (así evitas que alguien recorra todo tu contenido cambiando el ID de forma incremental).

Para ello tienes dos opciones:
1- Utilizar **URL Friendly**, que es lo que comenta Sebastian Araya en su respuesta.

2- Utilizar UUID en lugar de un ID autonumérico.
UUID = Universal Unique ID, es un standard que genera un ID alfanúmerico de 32 dígitos hexadecimales.
Tanto PHP, como las bases de datos (supongo que usas MySQL) tienen una función para ello.

Por lo que deberías cambiar en la DB, el campo ID de un INT autonumérico, a un tipo VARCHAR(32). Y generar un UUID para cada registro nuevo.

Para más información:

[Mysql UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)
[PHP uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Desconozco por qué no quieres que se muestre el ID, no debería ser un dato sensible en este contexto. Antes que encriptar, recomendaría usar slugs para evitar que se muestre y aprovechar de mejorar el SEO, esto es que la dirección sea por ejemplo:

> http://localhost/musica/noticiacompleta.php?noticias=una-noticia-de-musica

Para hacer esto necesitarías un nuevo campo en la base de datos, una columna "slug" y que guarde ese string, dicha columna debe ser única naturalmente, para que puedas indexar bien las noticias.

Si prefieres mantener la idea de encriptarla, necesitarías mandar el id encriptado y al recibirlo tendrías que desencriptarlo, pero es recomendable hacer ese proceso en PHP, no en Javascript ya que de lo contrario el ID quedaría expuesto en el JS. Para este fin podrías usar la función mcrypt_encrypt de PHP, pero ojo que a partir de PHP 7.1 la dejaron fuera.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Espero te sirva, dime si tienes dudas,
¡Saludos!